# Swap Elements in Lisp list

Tags: list, lisp, swap

I'm trying to implement a function that returns a list of LIST (each list in LIST is the result of two elements swapped in list). It's supposed to do a search based on the list formed from each swap. It is part of my program to solve the 8 puzzle problem. Here's what i have so far

```
(setq *LIST* nil) 

(defun swapped_list(lst)
 (loop for j in (positions_to_swap) do
    (setq *LIST* (rotatef (nth pos lst) (nth j lst))
      *LIST*)

(swapped_list '(11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19))
```

If `positions_to_swap` is `(0 2 5)` and `pos` is `4`, this should return
`((15 12 13 14 11 16 17 18 19) (11 12 15 14 13 16 17 18 19) (11 12 13 14 16 15 17 18 19))`

I've been spending countless hours trying to debug with no progress. I've tried many variants but none of them work.

Comment: Are you talking about the 8 queens problem? if this is the case you're making it much more difficult than it is (hints: -1- you of course know that queens must be on different rows, so just use a vector of column numbers -2- there are 8 available columns in the beginning and each time you place a queen you can remove that column from the list of available columns -3- there are only 15 direct diagonals (dd=x+y) and you can use the same logic -4- there are only 15 counter-diagonals (cd=x+8-y) and once again you can use the same logic...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If positions_to_swap is (0 2 5) and pos is 4, this should return ((15
>   12 13 14 11 16 17 18 19) (11 12 15 14 13 16 17 18 19) (11 12 13 14 16
>   15 17 18 19))

```
(defun swap (list position positions-to-swap)
  (loop for position-to-swap in positions-to-swap
        for rotated-list = (copy-list list)
        do (rotatef (nth position rotated-list)
                    (nth position-to-swap rotated-list))
        collect rotated-list))
```

Does the trick:

```
CL-USER> (swap '(11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19) 4 '(0 2 5))
((15 12 13 14 11 16 17 18 19)
 (11 12 15 14 13 16 17 18 19)
 (11 12 13 14 16 15 17 18 19))
```